# Need to check the condition if the value is `YES` or `NO`. And for the invalid values it should throw some error message

Tags: c#, if-statement

Here is the code what I have tried:

```
  if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Taskinfo.DoRollOver) &&(Taskinfo.DoRollOver != "YES" || Taskinfo.DoRollOver != "NO"))
  {
     throw new DataException("DoRollOver is not valid");
  }
```

But if I try to give the valid data such as `YES` or `NO` still it throws an exception.

Comment: For `(Taskinfo.DoRollOver != "YES" || Taskinfo.DoRollOver != "NO")` part, if you give `"YES"`, what will be `Taskinfo.DoRollOver != "NO"`? You are right, it will be `true`, So `false || true is true`.

Comment: Is DoRollOver an enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition is always true. If `Taskinfo.DoRollOver` is "YES" it is not equal to "NO", and vise-versa. You should use the `&&` logical operator, not the `||` logical operator:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Taskinfo.DoRollOver) ||
    (Taskinfo.DoRollOver != "YES" && // Here!
     T0askinfo.DoRollOver != "NO"))
{
    throw new DataException("DoRollOver is not valid");
}
```

Comment: Yes it works for the valid data `YES` or `NO` but if i try to give the NULL or empty values it throws an exception.

Comment: @Yathishkumar I buggered up the negation there. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Aiming for readability and simplicity I would split conditions:

```
if(Taskinfo.DoRollOver == "YES")
{
  // do smoething
}
else if(Taskinfo.DoRollOver == "NO")
{
  // do smoething else
}
else
  throw new DataException("DoRollOver is not valid");
```

Comment: This will not work, see the comment from OP on @Mureinik's answer: Yes it works for the valid data YES or NO but if i try to give the NULL or empty values it throws an exception

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can help you

```
 if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Taskinfo.DoRollOver))
  {
    if(Taskinfo.DoRollOver != "YES" && Taskinfo.DoRollOver != "NO")
      {
       throw new DataException("DoRollOver is not valid");
      }
  }else
  {
    //Do Something
  }
```

Comment: This will not work, see the comment from OP on @Mureinik's answer: Yes it works for the valid data YES or NO but if i try to give the NULL or empty values it throws an exception

Comment: no it won't, first you checked that if value is not empty or null , if value is empty or null it goes into else that you should handle if null or empty

Answer (score 1):

Try to change conditions like this

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Taskinfo.DoRollOver) ||(Taskinfo.DoRollOver != "YES" && T0askinfo.DoRollOver != "NO"))
{
    throw new DataException("DoRollOver is not valid");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you inverted logic a little bit.

```
if((Taskinfo.DoRollOver == "YES")||(Taskinfo.DoRollOver == "NO"))
{
  // do something
}
else
  throw new DataException("DoRollOver is not valid");
```

Also if TaskInfo.DoRollOver is string I would use TaskInfo.DoRollOver.ToUpper() - just in case.